# How is the damage for Reverse Slash calculated?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

I have a question regarding ESO skill [reverse slash](http://www.esohead.com/skills/28302-reverse-slash).

In the skill description it says: "Gives **up to** 300% more damage against enemies under 50%". The thing is, how is that up to computed? Is it random?

I tested against some random npcs (hit them with the skill while under 50%). My base damage on skill is 2988 dmg (let's round to 3k). So 300% more dmg would be 3k + 3*3k = 12k. Or if my interpretation on "more dmg" is wrong would be just 3*3k = 9k.

The damage I've done was something like 7k, 4k, 5k, 5k, etc. (averages at about 5.5k overall). Now... that seems way low than expected (even if I factor in armor). The other execution I use (nb - killers blade) seems to do way more damage and all reliable (no variations) - but... that's magical damage and it doesn't say "up to" in the description.

So... to sum up the question is: What is the real damage the skill does? How is that "up to" computed? Any1 else tested and got different results?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's been my understanding that skills that deal "up to" X% damage when the target is below Y% health" work on a *scaling* principle. Reverse Slash is one of these skills, as described [here](http://elderscrollsonline.info/reverse-slash) (and sort-of corroborated [here](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Reverse_Slash)).

This means that if your target is at 50% health you get no bonus damage. At 25% health you get half of the bonus damage. The closer to 0% you get, the more of the bonus damage you get.

Contrast this with skills lacking the "up to" modifier, like [Assassin's Blade](http://elderscrollsonline.info/assassins-blade). These are an all-or-nothing affair.

Comment: Almost right, but the scaling won't start unless health is below the given threshold (here: 50%). Above the threshold value your damage should be constant, unless there are other factors involved (like debuffs and the like).

Comment: @Mario Interesting. I guess that makes sense, updated accordingly (I haven't actually ever used any 2H skills), but it makes the skill seem pretty underpowered relative to other executes, huh?

Comment: Check the morphs. You'll get AoE damage or a generic boost for all 2H skills, if I don't confuse the skills right now.